# Is this kind of repeatable options possible with boost::program_options?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I have options `--foo` (short form `-f`) and `--bar` that need special treatment, they are repeatable and order should matter. So, for the following:

```
program --foo 1 --z -f 2 --bar 3 --x --foo 4
```

I'd like to range a key value map being able to construct `[("foo", 1), ("foo", 2), ("bar", 3), ("foo", 4)]`.

Please notice the order of this array of tuples, it's the same as that in the command line. I've discarded non-important options in the array, but they may be present in the command line nonetheless.

It seems the sole way to allow repeatable options with `boost::program_options` is calling `composing()` for any given option, but then, since each will store all their values in a vector, I lose the order I need for interlacing options.

So, can `boost::program_options` help with this?

### EDIT

I've asked for alternative software recommendations here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/31766/

And answered it using Poco.

Comment: can you accept --foo=1 --foo=2?

Comment: @RichardHodges Yes, I've inserted `--z` to demonstrate itens may not have strict ordering and are interchangeable. If you mean to restrict the request to accept it in a constrained manner, it would defy the question.

Comment: @RichardHodges if you know of an alternative small command line parser library that does this easily too, I'd appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can accept having to put an equals sign between the --foo and the value, this might do what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, const char**argv)
{
    std::vector<int> foos;
    boost::program_options::options_description desc("Command Line Options");
    desc.add_options()
    ("foo,F", boost::program_options::value(&foos)->multitoken(), "integers for foo");


    std::cout << desc << std::endl;

    boost::program_options::variables_map vm;
    boost::program_options::store(boost::program_options::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
    boost::program_options::notify(vm);

    std::copy(foos.begin(), foos.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

called with command line:

```
./a.out --foo=1 --foo=2
```

yields:

```
Command Line Options:
  -F [ --foo ] arg      integers for foo

1, 2,
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't help. In the question, both `--foo` and `--bar` are important.

Comment: ah i see. then maybe you want to use the linux `getopt` directly?

Comment: @pepper_chico documentation here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html

Comment: possibly. I'm not familiar with it, but also, I didn't wish to get C-low-level-like ...

thanks

Comment: @pepper_chico if you convert argv to std::strings, it's quite straightforward to parse them manually